# Fonts and character encodings

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, glyph

1. a) Do fonts know anything about coded character sets (Unicode, ASCII, etc.)? In other words, does a font file specify which coded character sets may use the font?
   b) I assume if a font supports certain coded character sets, then any character encoding (aka code page) for that coded character set can use this font?
2. a) Does a font's file also specify which code point a particular glyph is mapped to?
   b) Can a glyph be mapped to several code points at once? If yes, then how is correct mapping (of glyphs to code points) chosen when some application tries to map this font to a particular coded character set?
   c) Is a font basically a file with instructions how to draw its glyphs? If yes, then I assume each font has its own set of glyphs (ie. its own set of instructions on how to draw glyphs)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of questions, can't answer them all in detail so:

1. A. Yes, B. Yes
2. A. Yes, B. Don't Know, C. Yes

All of the details you'll want about .TTF/.OTF fonts are here: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm

If by putting Fonts in a code bracket like `Fonts` you mean an object in, say, .NET, then the WPF offers much of this info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748335.aspx.

Comment: "If by putting Fonts in a code bracket like Fonts you mean an object" No. Thank you for your help

Comment: 2B would certainly be *useful* for sets of characters like {µ, μ}, or {A, Α, А}